# Obtener un arreglo de elementos en respuesta PHP

Tags: php, mysql

quisiera obtener esto de respuesta [carlos,juan,pedro,xavier] del campo nombre_vendedor pero obtengo lo siguiente [[carlos],[juan],[pedro],[xavier]], Les adjunto mi codigo

```
public function getCventasvendedor() {
$response = array();
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM cumplimiento_ventas order by id");
// $stmt->bind_param("s", $estado);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $res = $this->getCventasByIdvendedor($row["id"]);
    if ($res == RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST) continue;
    else $response[] = $res;
}
return $response;
}

  public function getCventasByIdvendedor($id) {
   $response = array();
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from cumplimiento_ventas 
   where id = ? and estado = 'A' ");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
  if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $response[] = utf8_encode($row['nombre_vendedor']);       
  }         
  return $response;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hacemos una consulta con Mysqli, cada fila es un array distinto.

Respuesta Corta:

```
usa array_pop($this->getCventasByIdvendedor($row["id"]));
```

Respuesta Larga:
    Te doy un par de consejos.

1. Usa comentarios y nombres claros en funciones y variables para explicar lo que quieres hacer
2. El problema que estas intentado resolver puede hacerse mediante consultas SQL anidadas y es la mejor forma de hacerlo
3. Cuando vayas a hacer una consulta porfavor deja la estructura de tu base de datos o detalla más el problema
4. Te recomiendo mucho mas usar PDO que Mysqli, es mas seguro y maneja mucho mejor los parametros
5. No repitas codigo innecesario como loco, la consulta que estas haciendo se puede extrapolar a una funcion y se llamada desde ahí

Espero te sirva, saludos

igualmente te dejo un codigo de ejemplo.

```
function conectarABD($query, $bindearVendedor)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    if($bindearVendedor)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $vendedor);
    }   
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result;
}

function getVentasVendedor() {

    $response = array();
    $result = conectarABD("SELECT id FROM cumplimiento_ventas order by id", false);
    //conecto a la BD y tragio datos


    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $res = $this->getCventasByIdvendedor($row["id"]);
        if ($res == RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST) continue;
        else $response[] = $res;
    }
    return $response;
    //creo un array asociativo en donde guardo todos los ids de vendedores
}

function getVentasPor($vendedor) {

    $response = array();
    $result = conectarABD("SELECT * from cumplimiento_ventas 
    where id = ? and estado = 'A' ", true);
    //conecto a la BD y tragio datos

    if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $response[] = utf8_encode(array_pop($row['nombre_vendedor']));       
    }         
    return $response;
    //devuelvo los nombres de los empleados que ¿Cumplieron una venta?
 }

 ?>
```